# deque sorting (linear selection method with counting c++)

Tags: c++, sorting

It is necessary to sort the deck using the linear sorting method with counting, as far as I understand this is the usual sorting by counting, I can not implement this method, so the piece of code that calls the sorting function is commented out in advance, thanks in advance, I also apologize for the bad English.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
    deque<int> d1;
  int n;
void add(){
    cout << "Enter size:";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int x;
        cout << "Enter " << i + 1 << " elemet:";
        cin >> x;
        d1.push_front(x);
    }
}

void show(){

    while (!d1.empty())

    {
        cout << d1.front()<<" ";
        d1.pop_front();
    }
}

int main() {

    system("cls");
    int t;
    do {
        cout << "[1].add " << endl;
        cout << "[2].show " << endl;
        cout << "[2].sort " << endl;
        cin >> t;
        switch (t)
        {

            case 1:
                add();
                break;

            case 2:
                show();
                break;
//
//            case 3:
//                sort();
//                break;
//

            case 4:
                system("pause");
                break;


            default:
                cout << "SORRY TRY AGAIN PLEASE ";
                break;

        }
    }while (t != 4);
}
```